# How to define an interface for a class instance using class constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, prototype

I am building a application and part of the code allows developer to specify which component they want to render a certain part. I want users to know they need to implement an interface but I am not sure how to write typing correctly.

```
export interface ICustomComponent {
    templateObject: any;
}

export class MyComponent implements ICustomComponent {
}

export class MyLib {
    constructor(
        private yourComponent: ICustomComponent
    ) {}
}

new MyLib(MyComponent); <== Fails
```

I am writing code with Angular, and I cannot run new operator but let Angular to resolve and construct that component.

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components) an example that illustrates my problem.

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: what do you want to pass here `new MyLib(...);`? Instance like `new MyLib(new MyComponent());` or reference to the class?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components That example is to illustrate the problem only

Comment: so do you want to pass `MyComponent` to componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);`?

Comment: Yes but it is being pass in decorator like @Config({ useComponent: MyComponent })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MyLib` expects a class constructor, not class instance, you need to define an interface for a class constructor and specify that it returns the instance with the `ICustomComponent` interface:

```
interface ICustomComponent {
  templateObject: any;
}

interface ICustomComponentConstructor {
  new (...deps: any[]): ICustomComponent;
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements ICustomComponent {
  templateObject: any;
}

export class MyLib {
  constructor(private yourComponent: ICustomComponentConstructor) {
  }
}

new MyLib(MyComponent);
```

You can read about interface for class constructors and instances [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes).